# Can I wire this three wire fixture to my two wire junction box?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting

I have this three wire LED motion sensing outdoor fixture (labeled grnd, Neutral, Black) [image: Outdoor light bracket]

And I’d like to wire it to my current junction box which has only two wires, red (!!!) and white.  Is this possible?  It’s replacing my old fixture which actually was a three wire incandescent, which just used two:

[image: Old fixture, black here actually feeds into red outside]

Is this doable?  The garage actually has three wire wiring, just this box doesn’t.  I could do the old college try (it’s cheap enough that if i fry it i won’t cry) but i want to do the right thing.

EDIT the junction box.  Notice there’s a bolt hole labeled GRD. I have no idea if it’s actually Ground [image: junction box, with GRD Labeled bolt hole]

Comment: Please include a picture of the open junction box where the old motion detector was attached to and wired into.

Comment: Can you post photos that show the inside of the junction box in question please?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel question edited to add junction box.

Comment: What country / region ?

Comment: You can't see in the JB picture whether the wire is run in conduit.  There is a chance that the conduit is providing ground, in which case you'd ground to the box.  In this case the existing light head/box cover should be grounded to the box as well.  The % cost per foot of conduit including wires doesn't increase very much with adding a ground, so I like to use one even when not required.

Comment: Can you remove the crossbar and post another photo of the inside of the box please?

Comment: @P2000 US, illinois, northern burbs of Chicago. House is from 1952, I know the garage wasn’t part of original construction

Comment: @KH I can see the junction box on the back side (inside the garage) it’s conduit.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel the back side is exposed in the garage it’s run in conduit

Comment: @RichHomolka -- is that conduit rigid or flexible, metal or plastic?

Answer (score 1):

You could try it it will work or it won’t but it will not fry it.

I would pull a ground from one of the boxes that has it.

Pulling in a separate ground has been code compliant for a while now.
The ground has to come from a circuit fed from the same panel or you could tie at your grounding electrode system if closer (not usually)

There are a few motion lights that require the ground if this is one of those it won’t work but it won’t fry it so try it and you might want to pull a ground even if it works just to be safe.

Updated for additional photos that were added.
The ground may be from the conduit ? (if metallic) in that case the screw that shows the ground symbol would be a proper ground.
The motion sensor output is red tie the red to the black of the new fixture and white to white.
the concern with the new fixture getting fried is even lower as the existing fixture is controlling the motion sensor, as long as the maximum wattage for the motion light is not exceeded it should not be a problem.
The only issue that may still come up is the new fixture may not work on the output of the motion sensor but again it won’t fry it as long as the maximum wattage is not exceeded.
Electronic lights like CFL & LED’s may not work if the motion sensor is a simple SCR or silicon controlled rectifier / electronic switch that only turns on 1/2 of the sine wave. TRIAC’s or relay driven controls will normally work as they pass the entire waveform when turned on.

Answer (score 1):

What you show in pic 2 is the fixture. Looks like black and white are wired to the outlet box. (Red is the switched feed from detector to lights).

If there is a bare copper wire in your junction box, it should be connected to the green wired terminal.

Please include a picture of the junction box in your question. Then we'll know for sure.

Comment: Added pic of junction box. Thanks!

Comment: @RichHomolka ok great, I'll let ThreephaseEel comment on the code specifics, since there appears to be no ground wire. Meanwhile, you should be able to wire white to white, and red from junction to black of motion detector. It won't break anything if there is no ground. It's possible that the junction box itself is grounded, and the grounding of the detector's white cover will happen through the screw, or you have to run a separate copper or green wire from a bonding screw in the back of the box (you'll need to add a screw) to the green wire terminal of the detector.